# How to get full outer join in TimesTen

Tags: sql, full-outer-join, timesten

How do I get `full outer join` in TimesTen DB?

I tried this:

```sql
select t1.column1, t2.column2 
from table1 t1 
full outer join table2 t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column2;
```

This works in Oracle but when I run it against TimesTen it throws an error, that there is problem before "full".

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **full outer join** is not supported in TimesTen based on the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/timesten-18.1/TTSQL/TTSQL.pdf) (page 547). I have found alternative which returns same result using left join, right join and union.

```sql
select *
from (
        select t1.column1, t2.column2 
        from table1 t1 
            left join table2 t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column2
        union
        select t1.column1, t2.column2 
        from table1 t1 
            right join table2 t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column2
     )
```

Comment: That is not correct. FULL JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs.